# Group Policy applying only once?

Tags: group-policy, batch

For my own sanity can someone please advise why my GPO's to install application only works once? (both Machine level and User)

When I say once, I let the script install to test on a virtual machine. I then subsequently uninstall the application (using add/remove programs)

If I reboot or log back in...the script runs but the application never installs...? If I manually run the script..it works fine :S

Is my testing flawed perhaps..or something regarding batch script processing that I am overlooking?

Thanks

Mikoyan

Comment: Share the script and name of a failing application, or anything we write is a guess.

Comment: There are a few different ways to manage application installs through GPO, it'll be nice to know which one you're using.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way software installation via Group Policy works. When you install an application via Group Policy an entry for that application is written to the Registry at:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Group Policy\AppMgmt

Uninstalling the application from Control Panel doesn't remove this Registry entry, therefore the Group Policy will not be reapplied and the software will not be reinstalled.

If you want to "manage" the application via Group Policy and you install it via Group Policy, then you should uninstall it via Group Policy, which can be accomplished with this option:

[image]

If you want to redeploy the application (reinstall it on all targets where it has already been installed - and uninstalled in your case), you can do so like this:

[image]